# Y and Z are swapped

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, interface, transforms, axis

I have a weird problem and I have no clue how to get rid of it: The Y and Z are swapped in my project.

Basically, when I press G + Y, the object is moved on Z axis and vice versa, I have to press G + Y + Y to actually go for the Y. (Other transforms do the same, all modes)

It is only this project specific, other projects work normally (Y is Y and Z is Z). All meshes in this project behave the same.

I have probably misclicked something. How to get rid of it?

Using Blender 2.9

Comment: are you sure you've not switched to Trasform Orientation > Local or something else than Global?

Comment: Oh wait, it changed to Cursor after the transformation was done, so yes, it was not global, I will accept it as an answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have switched the *Trasform Orientation* to *Local* or something else than *Global*:

[image]